# JavaScript Module Pattern: which notation is preferred?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

Recently I began learning common JavaScript patterns and have a question about the **module pattern**.

Which notation (and **why**) is more convenient and preferred?

"Separated" notation:

```
var SeparatedApproachModule = (function() {
    var _private = { };
    var _public  = { };
    _private.doABarrelRoll = function() {
        //Do a barrel roll here
    }
    _public.buttonDoABarrelRoll_Click = function() {
        alert("I am doing a barrel roll!");
        _private.doABarrelRoll();
    }
    return _public;
})();
```

"Aggregated" notation:

```
var AggregatedApproachModule = (function() {
    var _private = {
        doABarrelRoll: function() {
            //Do a barrel roll here
        }
    };
    var _public = {
        buttonDoABarrelRoll_Click: function() {
            alert("I am doing a barrel roll!");
            _private.doABarrelRoll();
        }
    };
    return _public;
})();
```

Also posting other common or personal approaches you use and their advantages is appreciated.

Comment: I'd go for the second one, simply because I don't see the point of first defining an empty object, then adding properties, when you can add the properties right away in a literal.

Comment: Why put the private functions on an object at all if they aren't being exposed?

Comment: There are other possible notations, styles. Personally, I dislike both you mentioned.

Comment: @loganfsmyth: that's what private methods are for.

Comment: @bfavaretto It would be nice if you mention the style you prefer. :)

Comment: you should prefer the style best suited to your goal, or prefer the style already used in the project or... there are loads of opinions and proper use-cases.. Books *have* been written about it.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Sorry, not following. I just mean, why not just do `function doABarrelRoll(){}` or `var doABarrelRoll = function(){}`. It's already private due to the IIFE scope.

Comment: @loganfsmyth becouse this way you can include private objects with their methods as an (depending on case) cleaner 'internal'/'private' namespacing.

Comment: @loganfsmyth IIRC, IE used to misbehave..  In the former case, the function would escape into the global scope.  I imagine/hope it's been fixed in recent versions but couldn't tell you which one.

Comment: @SelvarajMA I didn't because there is no "right" style, as GitaarLAB said.

Comment: @Dennis You must be confusing it with named function expressions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, the most easy is to read, the better to remember later on. Instead of returning the object  what I do is to exposed the object to the global scope:

```
(function(AsGlobal/*or you can name it Public*/){

// private
var ModuleHelper  = {
  log : function(message){/*do stuff*/}

}

// Public
AsGlobal.Module = {

   save:function(userName){
      //saving code
      ModuleHelper.log('the user '+ userName +' saved the proyected');
   }

}


})(window);// the object that expose my objects to global scope
```